# Is This Language Regular or not?

Tags: regular-language, turing-machines, nfa, context-free-language, decidable

I have the language {4^(w⋅g)34^(g)|w,g∈NAT} over the alphabet {0,1}.

I need to find out if this language is recognizable, decidable, context free, regular or none of these.

How would i go about doing that or knowing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider any string of the form `4^a 3 4^b`. Can we find `w, g` for our `a, b`? Well, we know that `g` must equal `b`, and then we can choose `w = a + g`. Since `a`, `b` and `g` are natural numbers, so too must be `w`; the answer is that, yes, for any string of the form `4^a 3 4^b`, we have a string in your language.

The language of all strings of the form `4^a 3 4^b` is described by the regular expression `4* 3 4*` and, as such, your language is regular, context free, decidable and recognizable.

Suppose your language weren't regular; how could you tell? You could use the Myhill-Nerode theorem or the Pumping Lemma for regular languages to derive a contradiction from assuming the language were regular.

Suppose your language weren't context-free. You could use the Pumping Lemma for context-free languages to derive a contradiction from assuming the language were context-free.

Of course, if your language weren't decidable or recognizable, you could prove that in various ways as well.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, The alphabet is {3,4}. Does this change anything?

Comment: @user3706271 I didn't even notice you'd specified a different alphabet. As my answer makes no reference to the {0, 1} alphabet, it doesn't much look like it matters... unless I'm missing something.